# MinIO Error on distributed Cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, minio, kubernetes-statefulset

i try to deploy MinIO distributed Cluster on Kubernetes , i  wrote yaml file in the below link ,
i got errors logs from the pods , could you please review my yaml and support me for run minio as Cluster MinIO on Kubernetes
cluster 4 replicas, running on minikube    please check my yaml file here https://github.com/muhammedomar32/yaml  [enter link description here](https://github.com/muhammedomar32/yaml)

```
API: SYSTEM()
Time: 19:13:56 UTC 04/07/2023
Error: lookup minio-1.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
       host=minio-1.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local, elapsedTime=1 minute elapsed
       5: cmd/endpoint.go:396:cmd.Endpoints.UpdateIsLocal()
       4: cmd/endpoint.go:580:cmd.CreateEndpoints()
       3: cmd/endpoint-ellipses.go:351:cmd.createServerEndpoints()
       2: cmd/server-main.go:133:cmd.serverHandleCmdArgs()
       1: cmd/server-main.go:387:cmd.serverMain()

API: SYSTEM()
Time: 19:13:56 UTC 04/07/2023
Error: lookup minio-2.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
       host=minio-2.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local, elapsedTime=1 minute elapsed
       5: cmd/endpoint.go:396:cmd.Endpoints.UpdateIsLocal()
       4: cmd/endpoint.go:580:cmd.CreateEndpoints()
       3: cmd/endpoint-ellipses.go:351:cmd.createServerEndpoints()
       2: cmd/server-main.go:133:cmd.serverHandleCmdArgs()
       1: cmd/server-main.go:387:cmd.serverMain()

API: SYSTEM()
Time: 19:13:56 UTC 04/07/2023
Error: lookup minio-3.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
       host=minio-3.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local, elapsedTime=1 minute elapsed
       5: cmd/endpoint.go:396:cmd.Endpoints.UpdateIsLocal()
       4: cmd/endpoint.go:580:cmd.CreateEndpoints()
       3: cmd/endpoint-ellipses.go:351:cmd.createServerEndpoints()
       2: cmd/server-main.go:133:cmd.serverHandleCmdArgs()
       1: cmd/server-main.go:387:cmd.serverMain()

API: SYSTEM()
Time: 19:13:56 UTC 04/07/2023
Error: lookup minio-0.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
       host=minio-0.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local, elapsedTime=1 minute elapsed
       5: cmd/endpoint.go:396:cmd.Endpoints.UpdateIsLocal()
       4: cmd/endpoint.go:580:cmd.CreateEndpoints()
       3: cmd/endpoint-ellipses.go:351:cmd.createServerEndpoints()
       2: cmd/server-main.go:133:cmd.serverHandleCmdArgs()
       1: cmd/server-main.go:387:cmd.serverMain()
```

---

Answer (score 0):

What is your namespace? I think you are deploying on namespace other than `minio`. Replace your namespace in defining server:

```yaml
...

            image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2020-10-03T02-19-42Z
            args:
            - server
            - http://minio-0.minio.<deployed_namespace>.svc.cluster.local/data
            - http://minio-1.minio.<deployed_namespace>.svc.cluster.local/data
            - http://minio-2.minio.<deployed_namespace>.svc.cluster.local/data
            - http://minio-3.minio.<deployed_namespace>.svc.cluster.local/data
...
```

Comment: i added in namespace but still have error again ::"
Disk `/data` is a root disk. Please ensure the disk is mounted properly, refusing to use root disk.
Waiting for a minimum of 2 disks to come online (elapsed 1m18s)
Disk `/data` is a root disk. Please ensure the disk is mounted properly, refusing to use root disk.
Waiting for a minimum of 2 disks to come online (elapsed 1m18s)"

Answer (score 0):

```
May I ask how the problem was resolved in the end? I also encountered this problem,and the prompt is as follows.
API: SYSTEM()
Time: 06:26:57 UTC 06/28/2023
Error: lookup minio-1.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local: i/o timeout (*net.DNSError)
       host="minio-1.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local"
       8: internal/logger/logonce.go:118:logger.(*logOnceType).logOnceIf()
       7: internal/logger/logonce.go:149:logger.LogOnceIf()
       6: cmd/endpoint.go:430:cmd.hostResolveToLocalhost()
       5: cmd/endpoint.go:477:cmd.Endpoints.UpdateIsLocal()
       4: cmd/endpoint.go:675:cmd.CreateEndpoints()
       3: cmd/endpoint-ellipses.go:385:cmd.createServerEndpoints()
       2: cmd/server-main.go:222:cmd.serverHandleCmdArgs()
       1: cmd/server-main.go:531:cmd.serverMain()

API: SYSTEM()
Time: 06:27:02 UTC 06/28/2023
Error: lookup minio-2.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local: i/o timeout (*net.DNSError)
       host="minio-2.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local"
       8: internal/logger/logonce.go:118:logger.(*logOnceType).logOnceIf()
       7: internal/logger/logonce.go:149:logger.LogOnceIf()
       6: cmd/endpoint.go:430:cmd.hostResolveToLocalhost()
       5: cmd/endpoint.go:477:cmd.Endpoints.UpdateIsLocal()
       4: cmd/endpoint.go:675:cmd.CreateEndpoints()
       3: cmd/endpoint-ellipses.go:385:cmd.createServerEndpoints()
       2: cmd/server-main.go:222:cmd.serverHandleCmdArgs()
       1: cmd/server-main.go:531:cmd.serverMain()

API: SYSTEM()
Time: 06:27:07 UTC 06/28/2023
Error: lookup minio-3.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local: i/o timeout (*net.DNSError)
       host="minio-3.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local"
       8: internal/logger/logonce.go:118:logger.(*logOnceType).logOnceIf()
       7: internal/logger/logonce.go:149:logger.LogOnceIf()
       6: cmd/endpoint.go:430:cmd.hostResolveToLocalhost()
       5: cmd/endpoint.go:477:cmd.Endpoints.UpdateIsLocal()
       4: cmd/endpoint.go:675:cmd.CreateEndpoints()
       3: cmd/endpoint-ellipses.go:385:cmd.createServerEndpoints()
       2: cmd/server-main.go:222:cmd.serverHandleCmdArgs()
       1: cmd/server-main.go:531:cmd.serverMain()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34610717)